# Why can a 2d ArrayList not be converted to a 2d List my method innvocation conversion?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I have a method that accepts a 2d list (`List<List<String>>`) as a parameter. I when I try to pass it a 2d ArrayList `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` the compiler says that the two cannot be converted?

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    test(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
  }
  public static void test(List<List<String>> list)
  {
     return;
  }
}
```

I would think that test would accept an ArrayList since an ArrayList `is-a` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList<String>` is a `List<String>`, but that doesn't mean that a `List<ArrayList<String>>` is a `List<List<String>>`. In Java, generics are invariant, so this is disallowed.

You can pass an `ArrayList<List<String>>` to your `test` method.  Matching the generic type parameters exactly will always work.

```
test(new ArrayList<List<String>>());
```

Or, another way to get this to work is to have the `list` parameter in the `test` method have a wildcard:

```
public static void test(List<? extends List<String>> list)
```

or you can have the method match the parameters exactly.

```
public static void test(List<ArrayList<String>> list)
```

Both of those will allow you to pass in an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a `LinkedList<String>` in a `List<List<String>>`, but the same `LinkedList<String>` could not be added to a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Allowing what you are suggesting **would break that type safety.**

An `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` is not a `List<List<String>>`, not is it a valid argument for a parameter of that type.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem lies with the fact that someone who gets a `<List<List<String>>` would expect to be able to add both an `ArrayList<String>` and a `LinkedList<String>` to the same List which could never happen in real Java. Is this correct?

Comment: @fdsa That's the main issue. Note that this doesn't only apply to lists. It's just a visualizable example. This concept is true for all generics.